# Android Studio Emulator NO DC Attention

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I've a problem about Emulator. When I run the emulator, in the top left the screen there is a warning like:
[that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52358.png)

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

May be something related to NVIDIA GPU acceleration. Sorry, I don't know how to solve it.